# Updating Jira Cloud using the Unirest API

Tags: java, groovy, jira, unirest

I am able to access Jira cloud using Unirest Java library and basic authentication. Thanks to the Stackflowers for making it possible.

I would like to update one sample ticket's priority using the same. Below is the groovy code. Its not working but. Could you please identify where is my mistake.

```
     result = 
     Unirest.put("https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/TIC-1")
    .basicAuth("myuser","mypwd")
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .body([fields: [priority: [name: 'High']]]).asString

     println result.status
```

Error displayed is:

```
enter code hereCaught: java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization Impossible. 
Can't find an ObjectMapper implementation.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Serialization Impossible. Can't find an 
ObjectMapper implementation.
com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody.body(HttpRequestWithBody.jav
a:155)
com.mashape.unirest.request.HttpRequestWithBody$body$1.call(Unknown Source)
JiraClient.run(JiraClient.groovy:51)
```

All Maven dependencies added already and Unirest.get() request/responses working properly.

Comment: After spending sometime on it, I found that I need to implement ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code works. We need to implement Unirest ObjectMapper method. I am using the Java method as is from the below reference. It works with Groovy script as is:

```
/*Ref: <http://blog.pikodat.com/2015/09/11/tooltip-unirest-lightweight-http-
request-client-libraries/>*/

Unirest.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper() {
private com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = 
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

public <T> T readValue(String value, Class<T> valueType) {
    try {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(value, valueType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public String writeValue(Object value) {
    try {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
});
```

And you need to have additional Maven dependencies on the Jackson-bind:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

As a last step, add the missing import statements:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
import com.mashape.unirest.http.ObjectMapper
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest
```

And bingo! You can watch Jira updated externally in no time! Enjoy!!